# how to bubble pointer event to child overlapping each other in same parent

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a situation where I have several images overlapping each other and  on the pointer pressed I want to test if the clicked point is clicked on the transparent part of the image I want it to let go of the event and let the image below it test it out and repeat but it's passing the pointer event directly to the parent and remaining image is not being tested

```
<Grid Background="Red"
      Width="200"
      Height="200"
      x:Name="grdRed"
      PointerPressed="grdRed_PointerPressed"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid Background="Blue"
          Width="150"
          Height="150"
          x:Name="grdBlue"
          PointerPressed="grdBlue_PointerPressed"/>
    <Grid Background="Green"
          Width="100"
          Height="100"
          x:Name="grdGreen"
          PointerPressed="grdGreen_PointerPressed"/>
</Grid>



private void grdRed_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Red Pressed ");
    e.Handled = false;
}

private void grdBlue_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Blue Pressed ");
    e.Handled = false;
}

private void grdGreen_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Green Pressed ");
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

now when I click the green Color Grid

output is

```
Green Pressed 
Red Pressed
```

what I want is

```
Green Pressed 
Blue Pressed
Red Pressed
```

but I want it to go through the blue grid since the blue grid is below the green one,

I'll set the e.Handled as per the calculation if the clicked part is transparent I'll set it to false else true then it should go to blue grid I'll test it again and so on

So the question is how can I make the event get passed through the blue grid currently it moving from child to parent directly

thanks

Comment: You only need one event handler.  The event should check the grid object name or Background to get the color.  So use (sender as Grid).Background

Comment: actually the question is not about getting the name I want the event to bubble through blue grid

Comment: The Grid is passed to the event as the sender parameter.  So you just need to cast the sender to the correct type and then read the data from the sender.

Comment: I think I am unable to make you understand, so the situation is like I have several images overlapping each other and  on the pointer pressed I want to test if the clicked point is clicked on the transparent part of the image I want it to let go of the event and let the image below it test it out and repeat but it's passing the pointer event directly to the parent and remaining image is not being tested

Comment: Having one click event for multiple objects is very common.  When you click on an object the object is sent as the sender.  So if there are unique properties in the sender object you can read and tell which type object was clicked.

Comment: Why not assign a Click event to each object; the clicked object will be that which is visible. It will send it's properties to the click event when performed.

Comment: printing and event are not the problems is bubbling the blue and green grid are child to Red grid and overlapping each other now when I click on green it takes the pointer pressed event and test if it's going to handle it and for simplicity, I just set that to false in this example in the real world it will test and set according to it and when it is set to false I want it to go the next element below it not directly to the parent

Comment: I know I can do a single pointer event for all  it will be handled but the grid is a simple representation of my problem where I have custom control having images overlapping instead of the grid, so attaching the pointer and reading sender is not the aspect to the question, I don't understand why are you sticking to adding the single handler its not the issue I'll do that still it will print the same

Comment: event not getting invoked to the blue grid is the problem it is not firing at the blue one, directly goes to red one while the blue one is below the green one still jumps directly to red one

Comment: I'm afraid you can't bubble pointer event to child overlapping each other in same parent, derive from official document. *You can conceive of the routed event as bubbling from any XAML object element child element that fires the event, toward the parent object element that contains it.* but grdGreen and blueGreen are same level, bubbling only available for child -> parent.

Comment: So is it possible to consume the pointer press at the parent and then parent invoke pointer press for every child, right now I have implemented it but my parent is completely dependent on the type of child since the UI element does not have anything to directly invoke event from outside of an element and I have to use this in several places is it possible to invoke the pointer press of child from a parent,
right now I am using an interface that is created as a property to be passed in and if I get the view converted to interface I call a predefined function with the same pointer argument

Comment: You could simulate pointer press  children. you could use visual tree helper to find each children and then do InjectTouchInput.